# Event Capture in SVG

Tags: javascript, events, svg, dom-events

I'm trying to capture the event fired on the SVG element (rect in this case). However, `event` is not recognised and I get the console error:

> ReferenceError: event is not defined.

I called the same function on an HTML element and it worked fine. Is there any reason why the following does not work on SVG elements?

Here is the code:

```
<g class="piece filled" transform="translate(120, 0)">
  <!-- the following 'event' within 'playerMove' gives error -->
  <rect width="120" height="120" data-tile="1" onclick="playerMove(event)"/>
</g>
```

Javascript:

```
const playerMove = function( e ){ 
    console.log( e );
    let eTarget = e.target;
}
```

**EDIT**:
As per the comment, it appears to be a Firefox issue, is there any workaround to this? It seems to be working in Chrome. Thanks to *jessh* for the hint.

Comment: this code is working in isolated environment - http://codepen.io/jshawl/pen/XKogQa

Comment: I just tried it in FF & it too doesn't work. Then I figured he must be using Chrome, tried it & yes it does work! So, it is FF. Any solutions?

Comment: @RobertLongson No way! You are spot on. However, the same 'evt' passed as argument doesnt work on `HTML` elements in FF. There, `event` seems to be work fine. Would you know why this is?

Comment: Different specs, different rules. There was an attempt to standardise at one point but it broke too much existing content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change event to evt to produce this:

```
<rect width="120" height="120" data-tile="1" onclick="playerMove(evt)"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! However, the same 'evt' passed as argument doesnt work on HTML elements in FF. There, `event` seems to work fine. Would you know why this is?

Comment: Different specs, different rules.

Comment: @dandavis can you elaborate on that?